# How to insert data in SQLite db in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing SQLite db in my android application i want retrieve data from JSON and store in into SQLite db .I saw one of the example of using SQLite but I'm using different column name wchi is store into SQLite db .

But when i run the app I'm getting Error like =

> ((1) table contacts has no column named cost ,
>
> Error inserting phone_number=9533333333 cost=46456 name=Karthik    ,
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named cost (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(phone_number,cost,name) VALUES (?,?,?))

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_COST + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact._name); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_COST, contact._cost); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact._mobile); //Contact phone no

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_COST, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));

        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();

                contact.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.set_name(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.set_cost(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.set_mobile(cursor.getString(3));
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.get_name());
        values.put(KEY_COST, contact.get_cost());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.get_mobile());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.get_id()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.get_id()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

Comment: did this ran already once successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

to this

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

And check your work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try clear your app data then rerun the app, you may have had a different column before and run the app once (meaning the create table would not be called again).